# < ! - - more - - > tag not working

Tags: post-editor

I was playing around with the more tag . If I insert the more tag from the editor it seems to be working fine in my blog feed page like shown below :

[image]
[image]

But if I manually type in < ! - - more - - > in the post editor the code doesnt seem to work :

[image]
[image]

Could someone please explain what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to *add it in the Text mode*, not Visual mode. Otherwise, the tag will be printed as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Some themes provide modified support for the read more tag, even when it is added in text mode as @Sally-CJ suggested... When there is modified support for the read more tag you need to contact the theme developer to find out how to get it to work as you are expecting it to.